# Windows 2008 service creation permission

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service

What do I need to grant permission for creating a service in Windows server 2008 R2?

I have added the user to the local "Administrators" group.

This is the error message:

```
C:\temp>sc create test  binpath=c:\temp\test.exe
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Your command line, as entered in your question, isn't valid. There should be a space after the "=" in "binpath=". That's not your problem, though. That's probably just a transcription error.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up temporarily disabling UAC and installing service like so:

- Set **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA** to 0 as Administrator
- Reboot
- Create service as non-Administrator user
- Then set **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA** back to 1 as Administrator
- Reboot

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the cmd prompt as an administrator. By default you will not have the correct rights to do this.

Comment: This can be done by right clicking the command prompt > Run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Is test.exe really configured to create a service? You can't make just ANY exe be a service, the exe must be created correctly. I once tried adding notepad.exe as a service. Won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the Service Permissions
Right Click on  Service-> Properties -> Sercurity -> Give Full control to Users.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never used sc. Have you tried [installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984379(VS.71).aspx)?